# Will overclocking a mouse work on any computer or just the computer in which it got overclocked?

Tags: cpu, mouse

I am very new to overclocking of mouse.

I have a mouse that I use for competitive gaming which has 125Hz polling rate but that wasn't enough for me, so I overclocked it to 500hz and it works good but I am wondering that will it work on other computers as well? or do I have to overclock again on other computers too?

I used [this](http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/ok27/Web%20Assignment%20FINAL/index1.html#Windows7) site's instructions to overclock

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @Burgi Generally mice will be at a default 125hz so this means that windows will only update the mouse every 8 milliseconds, instead of every 1 millisecond if the mouse was polling at 1000hz

Comment: @Burgi generally it results in a smoother and more accurate mouse movement, particularly during games.  Many gaming mice can be specifically adjusted between 100 and 1000Hz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This overclocking doesn't actually modify the mouse.
It works by installing an special device-driver (which is software) on the computer to which the mouse is attached. This new driver allows for a higher polling-frequency if the mouse and the USB controller in the computer support it. (That is not guaranteed so this driver has a test-mode to see if it will work.)

To have this work on another computer you will have to install the overclock device-driver and other accompanying software on that computer and re-configure the settings.

Comment: What's the practical advantage of this? I can get increasing sensitivity for twitchiness but how/what does sticking a non supported driver to increase polling rate on a random mouse actually do?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Gamers seem to be of the opinion that that gives them slightly better responsiveness in games requiring very accurate mouse-timing to fire that bullet at the baddie at just the right moment. Personally I never noticed any improvement, just a higher chance of system instability due to the driver-hacks. I think it is just snake-oil, but there are millions of people on the internet that are convinced it helps them to be an uber-l33t gamer.